# Where exactly is the Vivaldi bank in Novigrad?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I've collected a bit of foreign coins, which merchants unfortunately don't accept as payment. The descriptions of these in the inventory helpfully states that I can exchange them for crowns at the Vivaldi bank in Novigrad.

I've been to Novigrad now, but it's really, really large and I didn't see the bank so far. Where exactly is this Vivaldi bank in Novigrad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article.](http://www.gosunoob.com/witcher-3/bank-location-in-novigrad/)

> Vivaldi Bank isn’t marked on the map. You’ll find the bank on the main square with the market. It’s the building with the large coin hanging above the door. It’s behind the bonfire were they burned witches once you arrived in Novigrad.

[This article](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/finding-the-vivaldi-bank-in-the-witcher-3/) has a picture of where the bank is located:

[image: Bank]

Comment: It IS marked on the map. It's marked as a Merchant. Like other Merchants, though, it only gets marked once you walk near it, and from then on it is visible on the World Map. Also, the loan he offers is 100 coins and asks for 130 coins in return, so 30% interest.